# generic function in javascript using backbone and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using backbone and Jquery and I have a backbone menu with a bunch of click able links.

```
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" id="main">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="profile">Profile</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" id="n-btn" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" id="dropdown1"> dropdown1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="dropdown2"> dropdown2</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I'd like to be able to do the following make a generic function such that I can click any of the links in the menu bar div above and have one generic function to handle all of the clicks.

Currently I have to create a separate function using jQuery for each id/herf

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#dropdown1").on('click.dropdown.data-api', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not target all the `a` tags directly, like: `$('#navbarCollapse a').on('clic....`?

Comment: @pyCthon - use `this.id` to refer to the id of the object that was clicked on.